Docker gets stuck on loading dockerfile
Docker gets stuck when building images on loading dockerfile:
=> [internal] load build definition from dockerfile                                                                                                                
=> [internal] load .dockerignore

I've tried using --no-cache, but it still gets stuck. The docker system df and docker builder prune also get stuck. Other commands work (I can still pull base images such as python:3.10-slim and I can list images/ containers).
I've tried to make a test dockerfile and I get the same results:
FROM python:3.10-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY print_message.py .

CMD ["python", "print_message.py"]

The system is running GNU/Linux.

Could you specify exactly what command (I assume docker build) do you run and with which options?

Can you verify that your Docker installation is working OK by doing docker run hello-world, please?

I run docker build --no-cache -t test-python .
hello-world is working
